# Switch between Fragments and Show hide the AlertDialog and maintain state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I have following scenario for my Android application.

- Step1: `Main Activity` loads the `Fragment1`.
- Step2: `Fragment1` shows a `AlertDialog` on some event as below
  [Fragment1 with AlertDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDxSP.png)
- Step3: Dialog has a camra icon on top right corner. When it is clicked it open camera to capture the photo as below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getCapturedImagePath());

((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(intent, Constant.CAMERA_CAPTURE);

((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left_layout, R.anim.left_to_right_layout);
```

- Step4: When pictured is captured, we redirect to another fragment called `Fragment2` in which we show the captured photo using below code.

```
FragmentTransaction fragTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

//Hide Fragment1
fragTrans.hide(fragment1);

//Add Fragment2
fragTrans.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment2, fragment2.getClass().getSimpleName());

fragTrans.addToBackStack(fragment2.getClass().getSimpleName());

fragTrans.commit();
```

It looks like [Fragment2 with AlertDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGSjw.png)

Here we have few problems.

**Problem 1:** It shows the same `AlertDialog` on `Fragment2` which was actually opened in `Fragment1` and `Fragment2` is loaded behind that dialog.
How to hide this dialog?

**Problem 2:** On the `Fragment2` we have `Correct` button when it is clicked we need to close the `Fragment2` and display the `Fragment1` with same alert dialog or you can say in same state it was before starting camera.
How we can do that?

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: Dismiss The dialog Camera icon Click in First Fragment Or Dismiss When Before Fragment 2 Transaction

Comment: @BrahmamYamani okay. So that will solve the problem1 and any idea about problem2?

Comment: Do You Maintain Any Data in Dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem1 solution:-**
  On click of camera icon from dialog.

```
camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            Utils.setDialog(dialog);

            FragmentTransaction fragTran = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if(activeFragment != null)
                  fragTran.hide(activeFragment);

            fragTran.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment2, fragment2.getClass().getSimpleName());
            fragTran.addToBackStack(fragment2.getClass().getSimpleName());
            fragTran.commit();
            activeFragment = fragment2;  

     }
 });
```

- **Problem2 solution:-** OnClick of 'correct' button from 'Fragment2'

  `correct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
          AlertDialog alertDialog = Utils.getDialog();
          if(alertDialog != null)
              alertDialog.show();
     }
   });`

It's work from me.

Answer (score 0):

For Add First Fragment write:

```
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativeLayout, fragment).addToBackStack(fragment1.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
```

In Fragment 1 show AlertDialog

```
 private void showDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setPositiveButton("Camera", null);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button button_positive = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            Button button_negative = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);


            button_negative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            button_positive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Your Camera Call
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                 // intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, "image path");
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, "REQUEST_CODE"); getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left_layout, R.anim.left_to_right_layout);
                    //make sure that don't call ==>  alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

After camera call for OnActivityresult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     //returned from camera
    // goto next Fragment ==> getActivity().fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativeLayout, fragment).addToBackStack(fragment2.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
   //  and for back to fragment 1 call in fragment 2 ==> //getActivity().fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragment2.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

when you arrive fragment 1 you got same state as you start in fragment

hope you will get solution

Comment: `//  and for back to fragment 1 call in fragment 2 ==> //getActivity().fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragment2.getClass().getSimpleName());` here i think it will be `fragment1.getClass().getSimpleName()).` is it correct?

Comment: I tried the above solution then 'Problem1' mentioned in question is still there. Also, I am able to get the state of `Fragment1` but If you observe the alert dialog in snapshot then we have a `EditText` for comment so if we enter any text to it. It doesn't remain when we popback. Please guide

Comment: try this for save instance state:@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("someVarA", someVarA);
        outState.putString("someVarB", someVarB);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        someVarA = savedInstanceState.getInt("someVarA");
        someVarB = savedInstanceState.getString("someVarB");
    }  in this store your edittext value and restore on fragment recreate

Comment: for more detail to save and restore fragment state please refer this link : http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en

Comment: @KailashChavda before try above solution we should resolve problem1.